# Actually emulate another terminal type instead of just declare

Tags: macos, terminal

When I change 'declare terminal as' value in profile's advanced preferences in Terminal App my terminal declares itself as another type but actually always behaves as xterm-256color type e.g.

```
echo $TERM
```

gives

```
xterm-16color
```

but It's still able to display 256 colors.

Is there any way to make Terminal App also behave as declared terminal?

Comment: The configuration only indicates to any binary what kind of Terminal capabilities they can rely on, it doesn't remove capabilities as such. Is there a specific issue you run into with this?

Comment: @nohillside I would like to see if my stuff (vim colorchemes, motds) looks decent in legacy terminals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible with Terminal.app, as it does not support emulating older terminals.

You'll have to use a different terminal program in order to see how your output looks in terminals that do not, for example, support 256 colors.

Note that `$TERM` (the variable used to commmunicate to user programs which kind of terminal you have) is not read by the Terminal software itself to configure it - it is read only by user programs such as a for example `top` so that it knows what kind of commands it can use. Not all software supports it however.

Also be aware that the usage of legacy terminals is very, very low. Desktop and laptop computers have for ages come with software that supports modern terminals with support for 256 colors. You'll need to either setup your computer purposefully for a 16 color setup, or have a really, really setup in order to be limited there.

Comment: Yes, you are right it was $TERM!

Comment: Most of Vim color files have 'term' options aside from 'cterm'. There must be some reason to substantially increase preferences file size ans decrease it's readability. Could you suggest terminal app that allows to emulate legacy terminals? It's curiosity after all.

Comment: I don't know if it is really "most" files - it doesn't seem that to me... but yes, there's ofcourse a reason why it was made. vim is an old program, so it is fair to assume that when the colorscheme feature was introduced, it was more common to meet terminal with b/w or 16 color support only (color schemes are from 2004 or earlier - you can look it up to find the correct year). Today it is very uncommon - I think it is only the Windows default terminal that took a long time to catch up with the rest. On macOS the default has been 256 colors for 8+ years, and the terminal supported it longer.